# How do I make a script or program to run certain commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, command, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get into writing scripts that execute in the terminal. I wanted to know what the best way to do this was. I want to start by making a simple script that will run four or five commands that will update a certain program on my computer and have that run every day at a certain time. I have a programming background, but I am unfamiliar with this kind of scripting. I would appreciate any advice or input such as what language to use.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question and will therefore probably be closed. If you want to run things at a certain time look into `crontab` and `anacrontab`. For your actual scripting, if you just want to run shell commands create a `shell script` or if you have a programming background you could perhaps look into `python`.

Comment: Shell scripting looks good for my needs. I have used python but just did not like its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
crontab -e
```

Then add following line beside the above command:

```
30 10 * * * script.sh
```

It will run everyday at 10:30 AM

Comment: Does this run every day at 6 am?
0 6 * * * myScript.sh

Comment: Yes of course @quillford it's as per your choice to select the time, I just gave an example.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that it used it correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to open a Terminal (such as Terminal, Terminator, etc) and then you run this:

```
touch myScript.sh
chmod 755 myScript.sh
```

The first command creates an empty file and then you give 755 permissions to it. It means that it will be readable and executable by any user in your machine. If you need more details about those permissions, you can refer to the documentation [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions). But, believe me, those permissions will work for the moment.

Now you can insert instructions into the file using several methods: You can open it with a text editor such as vi, etc; Also, you can echo those commands this way:

```
echo "ls /tmp" >> myScript.sh
echo "echo 'hello'" >> myScript.sh
echo "pwd" >> myScript.sh
```

If you open that file, you can find that it is simply a list of commands one at each line. Then, when you run the script, each command will be executed in order from top to bottom.
You can run the script using the following sintax:

```
./myScript.sh
```

Voilá!

Comment: that looks perfect. how can I get it to run every day at a certain time though?

Comment: You have to use cron tab for that @quillford

Comment: figured it out. thanks